# Wait times at Mt. Titlis?

Tags: transportation, switzerland, alps, lucerne

I'm heading to Mt. Titlis- end of August. but since the weather is uncertain, I want to wait and buy my Tell Pass there.
With the Tell Pass are the wait times really long in getting to Titlis, and would I need any prior reservations since it's peak season?

Comment: Someone informed me Tell Pass is unlimited and doesn't sell out so no need to buy in advance.

Comment: In Switzerland there are no compulsory reservations. So yes, you just get on the train to Engelberg and in Engelberg walk to the Titlis cable car, show your pass and get on. No reservations needed, nor are they possible.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Is it possible to simply get off the train and walk straight onto the cable car during peak season?  That seems to be part of the OPs concern.

Comment: There is a short walk involved from the train station to the cable car. So you get of the train, walk to the cable car station, and there you may, or may not have to queue up a bit. Bit the cable car runs regularly so I would not expect long queues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specifically need the Tell Pass to get onto Titlis, you can also buy a ticket at the station. A Titlis ticket costs CHF 96, Tell Pass costs CHF 190, so even if you take the train from e.g. Lucerne (which costs about CHF 20 both ways) it might be cheaper to just get the tickets you need (depends on your overall travel plans of course).

Neither the Tell Pass nor the standard ticket give you priority for the cable car though, so depending on demand you may need to wait a few minutes. But end of August is past the school holiday season, so at least during the week wait times should be acceptable.

Comment: This is perfect- thanks! I am buying the tell pass because we are also covering a few other places, and it's turning out to be more cost effective. But good to know that wait times will not be crazy and it's more on a first come first serve basis

Comment: @VPrah Saw your other question in the meantime, so yes Tell Pass may make a lot of sense. Have a good trip!